# How to debug a protected sheet with conditional statements (hiding/unhiding columns & locking/protecting cells) so it works faster

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of VBA code on a protected sheet (a request form) that unhides column F when certain values are selected in the columns D & E. On top of that, the code makes sure that if conditions are met, certain cells get unlocked so the user can type in them, oterhwise they remain locked for editing.

Everything works as desired BUT when filling out required information it really takes time for Excel to accept the entered data. For example when I type something into cell A (it doesn't really matter which cell is being edited) and press Enter it takes roughly 2-4 seconds for Excel to to process the edit.

When I was creating similar forms in the past, I never experienced such slowness. My question is: is there something in the provided code I can change so it works faster? Am I missing something? I did use `Application.Calculation`, 
`Application.ScreenUpdating`, `Application.DisplayStatusBar` and `Application.EnableEvents` in the code and it is slightly quicker but far from smooth.

I'd love to debug it so it is not as slow as now. Would appreciate any advise.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

    Pass = "4X4lZ7n0FxvCmQ?Z"

    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'THIS SECTION HIDES/UNHIDES THE 'SECURITY GROUPS' COLUMN ON IF PA ACCOUNT CREATION, MODIFICATION OR REACTIVATION IS REQUESTED OR NOT
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    'Unhides column F (security groups) if value in J17 is 1 (i.e. when PA account creation, modification or reactivation is requested)
    If Range("J17").Value = "1" Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=Pass
        Columns("F").Hidden = False
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=Pass

    'Keeps column F (security groups) hidden if value in J17 is 0 (i.e. when anything else is requested including PA account deactivation)
    ElseIf Range("J17").Value = "0" Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=Pass
        Columns("F").Hidden = True
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=Pass
    End If

    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'THIS SECTION LOCKS/UNLOCKS THE 'SECURITY GROUPS' CELL FOR EACH USER BASED ON IF PA ACCOUNT CREATION, MODIFICATION OR REACTIVATION IS REQUESTED OR NOT
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    'The 'Security Groups' cell for row 7
    If Range("J7") = "1" Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=Pass
        Range("F7").Locked = False
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=Pass
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=Pass
        Range("F7").Locked = True
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=Pass
    End If

    'The 'Security Groups' cell for row 8
    If Range("J8") = "1" Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=Pass
        Range("F8").Locked = False
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=Pass
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=Pass
        Range("F8").Locked = True
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=Pass
    End If

    'The 'Security Groups' cell for row 9
    If Range("J9") = "1" Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=Pass
        Range("F9").Locked = False
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=Pass
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=Pass
        Range("F9").Locked = True
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=Pass
    End If

    'The 'Security Groups' cell for row 10
    If Range("J10") = "1" Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=Pass
        Range("F10").Locked = False
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=Pass
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=Pass
        Range("F10").Locked = True
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=Pass
    End If

    'The 'Security Groups' cell for row 11
    If Range("J11") = "1" Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=Pass
        Range("F11").Locked = False
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=Pass
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=Pass
        Range("F11").Locked = True
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=Pass
    End If

    'The 'Security Groups' cell for row 12
    If Range("J12") = "1" Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=Pass
        Range("F12").Locked = False
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=Pass
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=Pass
        Range("F12").Locked = True
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=Pass
    End If

    'The 'Security Groups' cell for row 13
    If Range("J13") = "1" Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=Pass
        Range("F13").Locked = False
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=Pass
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=Pass
        Range("F13").Locked = True
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=Pass
    End If

    'The 'Security Groups' cell for row 14
    If Range("J14") = "1" Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=Pass
        Range("F14").Locked = False
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=Pass
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=Pass
        Range("F14").Locked = True
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=Pass
    End If

    'The 'Security Groups' cell for row 15
    If Range("J15") = "1" Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=Pass
        Range("F15").Locked = False
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=Pass
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=Pass
        Range("F15").Locked = True
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=Pass
    End If

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Unprotecting and Protecting a worksheet is significant slower in Excel starting from 2013. This is because the worksheet is encrypted in a more secure way (let's not discuss about the topic *how* secure)

So you should limit the number of times you are unprotecting / protecting a worksheet. You could set `ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=Pass` at the top and `ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=Pass` at the bottom of your routine, that should help.

However, there is a better solution: You can set a special mode of protection. This will protect the sheet from user entry and modification, but not from modifications by VBA code. You just need to know that this special mode is not stored in the Workbook, if you close and reopen it, it will be protected again also against modifications via VBA.

So what you have to do is to set this special protection mode when the workbook is opened. Create a Event-Handler for the `Open`-event and set the protection mode to `UserInterfaceOnly`. Maybe you have call the method for more than one sheet, and of course you need to define the value for `Pass` somewhere in your code. Now you can remove all other `Unprotect` and `Protect`-statements from your code.

```
Const Pass = "(your password)"

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheets("SheetName").Protect Password:=Pass, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
End Sub
```

Drawback is that it might be slightly slower to open the workbook.

P.S.: Now you have published your password on StackOverflow, maybe you should change it...